# How to Iterate through cells within particular columns

Tags: spreadjs

I have a spread sheet and I am trying to set a backColor for cells with empty values of some `particular columns`. Presently, I can iterate through the spread sheet and set the backColor for all cells with empty values, but I want to narrow it down to only check `particular columns`.
For instance if I have columns `Name`, `Location`, `Age`, `Net worth`, `Occupation`. I want to loop through cells within `Age` and `Occupation` columns alone, instead of all.

Answer (score 0):

I think a better option than iterating through cells is to apply the formatting to the range. For example `getRange("C:C").backColor("red");`
would set the background to red for the whole column.

if you only want to set empty values, then [conditional formatting](https://www.grapecity.com/spreadjs/demos/features/cells/conditional-format/basic-conditional-format/purejs) would be better.